# Getting the error "Trying to create a platform view of unregistered type: com.huawei.hms.flutter.map/map" when using huawei_map for Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-map-kit

Getting the error "Trying to create a platform view of unregistered type: com.huawei.hms.flutter.map/map" when using huawei_map for Flutter

Component:

```
HuaweiMap(initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(target: _center, zoom: _zoom))
```

Device: Huawei P40 Lite

All required setup has been completed correctly.

````
E/flutter (13684):      at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewsController$1.createVirtualDisplayForPlatformView(PlatformViewsController.java:192)
E/flutter (13684):      at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.create(PlatformViewsChannel.java:104)
E/flutter (13684):      at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.onMethodCall(PlatformViewsChannel.java:59)
E/flutter (13684):      at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
E/flutter (13684):      at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/flutter (13684):      at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:818)
E/flutter (13684):      at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/flutter (13684):      at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:363)
E/flutter (13684):      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
E/flutter (13684):      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8349)
E/flutter (13684):      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/flutter (13684):      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
E/flutter (13684):      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1055)
E/flutter (13684): , null, null)
E/flutter (13684): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:597:7)
E/flutter (13684): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:158:18)
E/flutter (13684): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (13684): #2      TextureAndroidViewController._sendCreateMessage (package:flutter/src/services/platform_views.dart:1043:18)
E/flutter (13684): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (13684): #3      AndroidViewController.create (package:flutter/src/services/platform_views.dart:748:5)
E/flutter (13684): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (13684): #4      RenderAndroidView._sizePlatformView (package:flutter/src/rendering/platform_view.dart:193:7)
E/flutter (13684): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (13684):```
````

Comment: hi@Stefan Zeuch,may i ask if you're using a flutter 1.0 or 2.0?

Comment: Have you tried sending mapType?

Comment: @shirley flutter 2.0

Comment: @JonathanIxcayau I have yes

Comment: @StefanZeuch,According to the team, the map kit does not support Flutter 2.0 by now. :(

Comment: @shirley ETA on supporting it?

Comment: @StefanZeuch yes，pls kindly see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your feedback, As confirmed by the team, the map kit does not support Flutter 2.0 by now.
But it is planned to launch map kit plugins for Flutter 2.0 around September,and i will let you know when it's released.